# How can I move an image slightly to the right while maintaining the same space on the left?

Tags: html, css

Trying to move an image that is already centered, over to the right slightly. I want to move the up and down arrows to the right so that the space on the right of the arrows matches the space on the left.

Screenshot of web page:
[image: Image of table and columns within the tables]

I tried adding padding to both the left and right side but I'm not trying to make the column that the up and down arrows are in bigger, I'm trying to make the space on the right side of the arrows smaller.

HTML code of one column of the table (all 5 columns of the table are near identical):

```
<td>
 <div class = "row">
  <div class = "column1">
    <img id="slideShirt" class = "IMGsize" src="..." alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1"> 
  </div>

  <div class = "column2">
    <img onclick="nextShirt()" class = "arrow" src="..." alt="Up arrow">
    <br>
    <img onclick="previousShirt()" class = "arrow" src="..." alt="down arrow">
  </div>
 </div> 
   <h3 class = "shirt" id ="shirtName">
     <center>Shirt 1</center> 
   </h3> 
</td>
```

CSS code for class "row", "column1", and "column2":

```css
.column1 {
  float: left;
 }
  
.column2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }

/*
 Sets the size of the arrows in column 2.
*/

img.arrow {
 height: 115%;
 width: 30%;
}
```

I'm not sure why there is more space on the right then the left. I like how much space is in between the image and arrows but there's too much space on the right of the arrows. I realize that the image may need to increase in size so that the white space to the left of the arrows stays the same.

Comment: Please provide working example images to have a [mre].

Comment: Just to note that the center tag is now deprecated. Use CSS instead.